# How to apply typescript for firebase functions in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm in the process of converting one of my React Firebase project to typescript with help of react-redux-firebase documentation. One of the problem I'm having is how to correctly define types for the fireabase and firestore functions. For example, here's my React reducer action function.

```
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { PROJECT_TYPES } from "../../action-types/project";
import { PROJECT_ACTION } from "../../action/project";
import { IPROJECT } from "../../interface/project";


export const createProject = (project: IPROJECT) => async (dispatch:Dispatch<PROJECT_ACTION>, getState:any, { getFirebase, getFirestore }:any):Promise<void> => {

    const firestore = getFirestore();
    firestore.collection('projects').add({
        ...project, 
        authorFirstName: getState().firebase.profile.firstName,
        authorLastName:getState().firebase.profile.lastName,
        authorId:getState().firebase.auth.uid,
        createdAt:new Date()
    }).then(() => {
        dispatch({
            type: PROJECT_TYPES.CREATE_PROJECT,
            payload: project
        })
    }).catch((err:any) => {
      console.log({err})
        dispatch({  type: PROJECT_TYPES.CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR, payload: err })
    })
 }
```

As see above code I've defined the type as **any** to the getState, getFirebase and getFirestore functions. I'm not happy with that type, so I want to know is there a correct way to define these types?

Instructions followed from the http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/api/getFirebase.html link

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a google search, returned this: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/using-firestore-with-typescript-in-the-v9-sdk-cf36851bb099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information for the type definitions for [React Redux](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript) may be found in the @types/react-redux typedefs package on NPM. The types export certain helpers in addition to typing the library methods, making it easy to construct typesafe interfaces between your Redux store and your React components.

Because the react-redux package depends on @types/react-redux, the type definitions will be installed together with the library. Otherwise, you'll have to explicitly install them (using npm install @types/react-redux, for example).

Reading the documentation in the comments, the information could be useful, but I found more documentation that might also help with your project:

- [Using React + Redux with Firebase & TypeScript](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-react-redux-with-firebase-typescript-4d47f32d7048).
- [The simplest way to combine React, Redux and Firestore
  (Typescript)](https://medium.com/exelerate/the-simplest-way-to-combine-react-redux-and-firestore-typescript-353bea49cdbd).